# Input witch speech recognition in UE5?

Tags: game-development, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

did somebody know how to use speech recognition in unreal engine 5 as a Input like if I say go left, the character go also left? Or exist any tutorial for that?

Answer (score 0):

You could build your own server which reacts to voice inputs.
I'm using https://hub.docker.com/r/alphacep/kaldi-en for a few projects with a nodejs wrapper which reacts on http or websocket connections. You should cache language models. It may still be a laggy experience even with low network latency.